# How to measure FM deviation for pilot signal?

Tags: frequency-modulation

I'm trying to calibrate my FM signal generator, but don't have the required FM detector.  The instructions say:

1. Turn pilot ON, comp OFF
2. Set pilot to 10% deviation
3. Verify detector says 7.5kHz, or adjust R102

If I use my HP E4406A connected to the VSA software, the second plot is supposed to show the FM deviation.  Why is the resolution so bad?  It seems to work ok when checking with a 1kHz tone at 67.5kHz deviation.

[image: FM pilot on HP VSA software]

Edit: This is what the signal looks like with FM mono and 1kHz tone, comp only
[image: fm mono 1khz tone]

Comment: What is the frequency of your FM signal?

Comment: its 90MHz for this test

Comment: Is your E4406A / VSA software capable of giving you a clean detected FM waveform at that frequency?

Comment: Your screen capture seems to indicate that it's only measuring up to 40kHz.

Comment: the first one is the demodulated carrier at 90MHz, that looks pretty clean unless I misunderstood the question.  The PC software has to demodulate it, as far as I know the E4406A  can't demodulate analog

Comment: On the green graph it says "Left 0Hz" "Right 40kHz".  That usually means the start and stop frequency of the graph.  Although  0Hz also seems suspect.

Answer (score 1):

Me? I would cheat!

Given you have a spectrum analyser and (presumably a signal generator), I would use the Bessel null method to measure exactly what amplitude of sine wave was required at the modulator input to give 75kHz deviation, then just set the pilot tone amplitude to 10% of that level, job done.

You feed the modulator (with preemphasis DISABLED) a sine wave of exactly 31.1894kHz and then turn the level up while watching the carrier amplitude (ignore the mess of sidebands), as you turn up the carrier amplitude will drop before rising again, that first null will occur when you are deviating exactly 75kHz peak. Measure the amplitude as accurately as you can with the deepest null you can manage, and then set the pilot to 1/10th of that level, job done.

Comment: the equipment is designed for fm radio, which stops at 15k, but even if I use a second or third Bessel null, what am I measuring when I go to set the 7.5kHz signal to 1/10 the 75kHz value?

Comment: You have a stereo encoder (MPX generator) which is the thing with the pilot tone level control) feeding some kind of an FM modulator? You hook your signal genny directly to the modulator input bypassing the stereo encoder, and figure out how many volts corresponds to 75kHz of deviation (By the Bessel null method), then for 7.5kHz deviation the required voltage is 10% of that needed for 75kHz so you set the pilot level to give that voltage at the modulator input once it is hooked back up, simples. Note that often the modulation level changes as you change TX frequency, so set that first.